# Postgresql performance difference between IsActive=false and Not IsActive

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I've a `Brand` table and while checking query plan, saw this.

Query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  select  * from "Public"."Brand" where "IsActive" =false ;
```

Query Plan

```
Seq Scan on "Brand" tb  (cost=0.00..27.11 rows=109 width=679) (actual time=0.009..0.115 rows=109 loops=1)
  Filter: (NOT "IsActive")
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2
Planning Time: 0.081 ms
Execution Time: 0.144 ms
```

Query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  select  * from "Public"."Brand" where not "IsActive";
```

Query Plan

```
Seq Scan on "Brand" tb  (cost=0.00..27.11 rows=109 width=679) (actual time=0.019..0.194 rows=109 loops=1)
  Filter: (NOT "IsActive")
  Rows Removed by Filter: 2
Planning Time: 0.147 ms
Execution Time: 0.238 ms
```

As you can see above, both `IsActive=false` and `(not "IsActive")` executed as `NOT IsActive`.

Is there any difference between `IsActive=false` and `not IsActive` or even `IsActive<>true` ? Should I worry about which one to choose?

Answer (score 0):

`"IsActive" = FALSE` and `NOT "IsActive"` are the same, otherwise the PostgreSQL optimizer would have a bug.
`"IsActive" <> TRUE` is also the same, and the optimizer also reduces it to `NOT "IsActive"`.

Comment: To enlarge on this correct answer a bit, searching BTREE indexes for *equality to a particular value* is often more efficient than searching for an inequality. It's possible to random-access BTREEs to exact values.